# The default look of Icefaces and how to customize it

Tags: java, icefaces

I have a question about styling Icefaces. I have a minimal application that can use Icefaces components, but when I use them and view the page, the components are not styled (for example the buttons have the default look and tabs have no look at all, no images, nothing). I was wondering why that is and what I should do so I would get the default Icefaces look to work.

Next thing I don't get is how do I customize the look by changing some default css style classes that get applied to the components automatically, so every component I use gets the changed style.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you take one of the existing style-sheets, which are included within the ICEfaces package (check the *resources* folder of the downloaded ICEfaces-1.8.1-bin.zip):

- rime
- royale
- xp

You can preview them in the [ICEfaces showcase](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

Include it within your *.xhtml file via the `<ice:outputStyle>` tag:

```
(portlet)
<ice:outputStyle href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime-portlet.css"/>

(servlet)
<ice:outputStyle href="./css/demo_template.css"/>
```

Starting from here, feel free to either manipulate the chosen stylesheets or - which I favor - include your own stylesheets after ICEfaces' ones and overwrite the needed styles.

Regarding your second question:
Basically every ICEfaces component has its own style class. Just browse around the showcase and inspect the components with Firebug. I've not found many classes, which have been reused between different components. Therefore, you'll have to customize each and every component on your own - or apply your own common style class to every component you use via the styleClass property.

```
<ice:panelGrid styleClass="myCommonStyleClass">
<ice:inputField styleClass="myCommonStyleClass">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
There are three predefined ICEfaces style sheets included:

(1) xp.css
(2) royale.css
(3) rime.css

Developers may also create their own custom style sheet based on a predefined ICEfaces style sheet. If the style class names match those defined in the ICEfaces style sheets, the ICEfaces components will use the specified styles by default, without the need to specify the style class names explicitly on each component.

(1) Where to find CSS class names ?

IMPORTANT : The default CSS class names associated with each component are listed in the component's TLD (taglib) description.

(2) How To use a predefined style :


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" />

     OR


<ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />

(3) Is there any Advantages of using ICEFaces OutputStyle ?

The ice:outputStyle component has the following advantages over the HTML link tag:

- Automatically includes browser-specific variants of the main style sheet in the page to adapt the theme styling to account for differences in each browsers' CSS support. See the TLD (taglib) documentation for the ice:outputStyle component for details.
- Provides the ability to dynamically change the theme style sheet at runtime via a value binding on the component's `href` attribute.

(4) What is meant by xmlhttp ?

The xmlhttp->css->xp path is automatically resolved by ICEfaces and all needed resources are loaded from the ICEfaces.jar

Hope this helps..!! :)
```